# how to add values coming from hmtl form to an array saved as json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to add values into my Array saved as Json file with the following structure:

```
[
      ["1","16/10/1997","TLV","Leonardo","3","40","21","Some Name"],
      ["2","17/10/1997","TLV","Leonardo","6","42","21","Some Name"],
      ["3","17/10/1997","TLV","Leonardo","9","39","21","Some Name"]
]
```

the new record is coming from an HTML form using Get method
so I have tried the following code:

```
    <?php 
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') { 
            $NewDive[] = array( 
                $NewDive[0] = $_GET['TB_DID'],
                $NewDive[1] = $_GET['TB_DDate'],
                $NewDive[2] = $_GET['TB_DSite'],
                $NewDive[3] = $_GET['TB_DCenter'],
                $NewDive[4] = $_GET['TB_Depth'],
                $NewDive[5] = $_GET['TB_DTime'],
                $NewDive[6] = $_GET['TB_Oxygen'],
                $NewDive[7] = $_GET['TB_DBoddy']);
                 
            $file_name = 'test.json'; 
            file_put_contents("$file_name", json_encode($NewDive), FILE_APPEND);
        } 
    ?>
```

but the result I'm getting for the additional record is something like this (double record):

```
 ["4","20/10/1997","TLV","Leonardo","9","39","21","Some Name",["4","20/10/1997","TLV","Leonardo","9","39","21","Some Name"]]
```

What I'm doing wrong?
also, what is the best way to add the new record into the full Json file?

10x
Yakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append JSONs. You need to read the file, decode the JSON into an array, add the new element to the array, and write it back out.

Also, you shouldn't assign to individual array elements at the same time as you're pushing to the same array.

```
    <?php 
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') { 
            $file_name = 'test.json';
            $contents = @file_get_contents($file_name);
            $NewDive = $contents ? json_decode($contents, true) : [];
            $NewDive[] = array( 
                $_GET['TB_DID'],
                $_GET['TB_DDate'],
                $_GET['TB_DSite'],
                $_GET['TB_DCenter'],
                $_GET['TB_Depth'],
                $_GET['TB_DTime'],
                $_GET['TB_Oxygen'],
                $_GET['TB_DBoddy']);
                 
            file_put_contents($file_name, json_encode($NewDive));
        } 
    ?>
```